# Why is App.config a more secure location for storing a connection string than in the source code?

Tags: .net, security, connection-string, app-config

Simple question, I know that storing a connection string in plain text in your source code is a bad idea, as somebody can use a tool like Ildasm.exe to decompile and subsequently view your connection string, but why is using App.config any safer?

Surely this config file sits right beside your executable, so if somebody has access to your executable for decompiling, they also have access to your config file and therefore your connection string.

So my question is why is App.config a more secure location for storing a connection string than in the code?

Comment: What gave you the idea that it is more secure? It is easier to change a connection string in a config file than inside code - that's why it is normally considered a better location for them.

Comment: You can encrypt the app.config file. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can secure any info in config file. This link to [Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) explain how

UPDATE:
Sorry for broken link, I update it and add article title. The solution is using **RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider**. I created a simple method in my WebUtility helper class:

```
public static void CheckWebConfigSecured(string webPath, params string[] sections)
{
    Configuration confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(webPath);
    bool done = false;
    foreach (string section in sections)
    {
        ConfigurationSection confSection = confg.GetSection(section);
        if ((confSection != null) && !confSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            confSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
            done = true;
        }
    }
    if (done)
    {
        confg.Save();
    }
}
```

Which I call from **Global.asax.cs** on **Application_BeginRequest**

```
WebUtility.CheckWebConfigSecured(
    context.Request.ApplicationPath,
    "connectionStrings",
    "appSettings",
    "log4net");
```

Where *connectionStrings*, *appSettings* and *log4net* are web.config sections which I want to protect.

As result these sections in Web.config file on the server are look like following example, after first visit to the site after deployment:

```
<appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
          <CipherValue>YbjvJF6IpTaEFb58ag1O ... HJm1uzA=</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
      </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>mzJ2PoteOG7ZpAs922sounmG ... 02D3ZiM1PCliSw==</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

App.config as such is not more secure if you leave the connection string in clear text.
However, you can encrypt parts of config file, and that will improve security.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18209/Encrypting-the-app-config-File-for-Windows-Forms-A

You could also store connection string in an encrypted registry key if you don't want to store it in the file in your application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the connection string in code in a literal string is easily retrievable from the compiled binary using a simple hex editor unless the binary has been obfuscated.

App.config is not necessarily more secure but there is an option to encrypt information in the App.config which would be much more secure than clear text.

App.config can also be secured at the ACL level on the file system as well.  This can complement security, but isn't always practical as typically, host server administrators will have permission to the file.